# BroadcastReceiver gets killed or unregistered by the system

Tags: java, android, broadcastreceiver

I know it is the common problem and the common solution is to register the intent filter in manifest, not in the code. But the manifest registration doesn't work for some actions, for example for `android.intent.action.SCREEN_OFF` and `android.intent.action.SCREEN_ON`.

How can I make sure that such receiver works *exactly* until it is unregistered by me in the code?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I make sure that such receiver works exactly until it is unregistered by me in the code?

You can't. Any component that registers a receiver can itself be destroyed due to inactivity/old age, to reclaim RAM for use by the rest of the OS. Plus, of course, the user can get rid of any component whenever the user wants via task killers and the Settings application.

The closest you can come is to use a service that also calls `startForeground()` and putting a `Notification` in the status bar. Again, the user can still get rid of it whenever desired. You would then have to convince the user that your application's value is worth the cost of the everlasting service and the screen space for the `Notification`

Comment: I believe that I can use alarm manager to re-register the receiver in a given period of time. Thanks for the info anyway.

Comment: @jacek: That will not help if users get rid of you via task killers/force-stop, as that removes all scheduled alarms as well.

Comment: I know, but that is ok. The most important thing is that I don't want the receiver to die automatically.